# "Впридачу": слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно пишется слово "впридачу"? По идее, это наречие и должно писаться слитно, но я слышала, что по поводу этого слова существуют разногласия. Так как же все-таки правильно его написать?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

НАРЕЧИЯ действительно должны писаться слитно или через дефис, но существует большое количество НАРЕЧНЫХ ВЫРАЖЕНИЙ, которые относятся к классу обстоятельственных существительных и пишутся раздельно, например:

в меру, на износ, на лад, в струнку, в ряд, в прах, на славу, в заключение, в придачу, в насмешку, в новинку, на зависть, на вкус, на лету,  на бегу, на виду, по памяти, с ходу,  с налёта, с размаху,  с разбегу, с изнанки, от силы.

Чтобы убедиться в правомерности их раздельного написания, нужно проверить значение падежа, например: отдать (как?) в придачу (в добавление к чему-то) - это В.п., определяющий характер действия (сравнить: продавать в розницу, купить в складчину, приобрести в рассрочку).

Тема, связанная с различением наречий и наречных выражений, достаточно сложная, поэтому свое решение лучше сверить со словарем.

Answer (score 4):

Д.Э. Розенталь от 1967 года за раздельное написание.

http://rosental-book.ru/ortho_xiv.html#sect58

Comment: Дарья, такие ответы надо подтверждать цитатой и ссылкой. Розеталь в сети есть, найти несложно, если знаете, где и что искать.

Answer (score 3):

Нормативно - раздельно.
http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%E2%EF%F0%E8%E4%E0%F7%F3

Никаких разногласий.
А почему Вы считаете, что раз наречие, то слитно?

Answer (score 0):

⇒ София
Вопрос (как?) - типичный наречный вопрос, указывающий на наречное значение словосочетания "в придачу", как вы с его помощью определили винительный падеж? Как вы собираетесь проверить с его помощью значение падежа и что это такое? <не сарказм>

⇒ behemothus
Наречия, как формирующаяся часть речи, имеют тенденцию к **слитному** написанию, и многие подобные сочетания предлога с именем существительным уже пишутся слитно, например: влево, вправо, вверх, вниз, навскидку (наречия образа действия, отвечают на вопрос (как?)); в то время как другие, хотя и прочно вошли в обиход, по-прежнему пишутся раздельно: в целом, в общем - единого подхода, правила нет, нужно сверяться со словарём.

Comment: Два комментария в одном Неответе. Лучше удалить и — по местам.